# C# / ASP.NET - Web Application locking

Tags: c#, asp.net, synchronization, locking

I'm working on a C#/ASP.NET web application, and I have a number of situations where I need to do locking.  Ideally, I want the locks to act independently, since they have nothing to do with each other.  I've been considering `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` and a few ways of using `lock()`, but I have a few questions/concerns.

It seems like MethodImplOptions.Synchronized`will essentially do`lock(this)`.  If that's the case, it seems like a thread entering any synchronized method would block *all other* threads from entering *any* synchronized method.  Is that right?  If so, this isn't granular enough.  At that point, it seems like I may as well use Application.Lock.  (But please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Concerning `lock()`, I'm trying to figure out what I should pass in.  Should I create a set of objects solely for this purpose, and use each one for a different lock?  Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

My preference is to create an object specifically for the lock.

```
private object lockForSomeResource = new object();
```

in the class that is managing the contentious resource.
Jeff Richter posted an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188793.aspx) I read some time ago that recommended this.

You need to think carefully about designing these as a hierarchy if there is any code within a lock that needs another lock. Make sure you always request them in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted a similar question on this forum, that may help you. Following is the link

[Issue writing to single file in Web service in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119548/problem-in-writing-to-single-file-in-web-service-in-net)

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose some static reference or a singleton, and lock() that.

Maybe you can care to explain why you need such locking and what you will use it for?

Comment: There are a number of application variables and collections/lists which are read and modified by requests.  Each request only "cares" about a certain subset of those variables.  I'm trying to maximize throughput, so the more granular I can make the locks, the better.

Comment: OK, but then applying locks/synchronization on the method level does not appear granular to me at all, that's why I asked...

Comment: The methods themselves only contain the sets that I need to lock - nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Creating discrete object instances at static/application level is the best way for  plain exclusive locking.

Should also consider if reader/writer lock instances at application level could also help improve your application concurrency e.g. for reading and updating lists, hashes etc.